# How can I use @types dependencies in my Angular 2 application?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, npm

I have installed Twitters bootstrap using 'npm install @types/bootstrap --save'. My package.json dependencies look like this:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.32",
    "@types/d3": "^4.5.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  }
```

I'm trying to do a single import into my app.modules or app.components (not sure where it belongs), but every time I add `import { Bootstrap }   from '@types/bootstrap'` it says localhost:3000/@types/bootstrap not found.

Comment: please check this discussion you may find solution https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/1035

Answer (score -2):

You will never import from `@types`.  These contain the typescript definitions for other modules, not actual code.  So the pattern is...

1. import from `@x/y`
2. `tsc` tries to find `@x/y`
3. If `@x/y` doesn't contain types then `tsc` searches `@types/@x/y` for types

In other words.  You will need to install bootstrap and import bootstrap.  Usually the pattern is:

1. `npm install --save bootstrap`
2. `npm install --save-dev @types/bootstrap`

Comment: This has been down voted a few times.  Can someone help me explain why next time?  I'm happy to research a better answer but I don't understand what is missing.